# R tolower function

Tags: r

how to convert a data frame to lower case

if I use tolower(df) , my workspace crashes.X

PS: my df has around 400000 rows and 4 columns and I would need all the text inside that df to be in lowercase

Comment: `?tolower(x)` says that `x` is a character vector

Comment: As @rawr said, you probably need `df[] <- lapply(df, tolower)`

Comment: you can also try: `data.frame(tolower(as.matrix(df)))`

Answer (score 2):

try:
x<- apply(x,2,tolower)

This works for smaller dataframes. You might have to chunk yours up and then rebind them for that many rows though.